# (C programming) Read a text file char by char and remove spaces and hyphenation in front of dots and commas

Tags: c, file, char

Read a text file char by char and remove spaces and hyphenation in front of dots and commas.
The use of string.h functions is **forbidden!**
I tried to write a program that removes a single hyphen/space, thought I need to delete all of them, e.g. one, two or more spaces in front of a dot. As a newb, it's not clear to me, I think
I don't fully understand how to use the while loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *f1;
    FILE *f2;
    char ch1;
    char ch2;
    char space=0;

    if(argc==1)
    {
        printf("Unknown file\n");
        return 1;
    }

    f1=fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if(!f1)
    {
        printf("Error opening input file\n");
        return 2;
    }

    f2=fopen(argv[2], "w");

    if(!f2)
    {
        printf("Error creating output file\n");
        return 3;
    }

    while((ch1=getc(f1))!=EOF)
    {
        if((ch1==' ')||(ch1=='\n'))
        {
            if((ch2 = getc(f1))=='.')
            {
                putc('.', f2);
            }

            else 
            {
                putc(ch1, f2);
                putc(ch2, f2);
            }
        } 
        else putc(ch1, f2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Please, explain that to me!

Comment: You're closer than you may think.

Comment: Hint: you need a counter and possibly a buffer and/or  a state variable. hint2: ch1 and ch2 should be ints, not chars.

Comment: Hint: You can take advantage of that you can move your file pointer freely in the file with `fseek()` and see where you are with `ftell()` (just make sure you open the file in binary mode `"rb"`.

Comment: Well, I was told to use just text file mode. (add that to limitations like making this sans using string.h)

Answer (score 0):

Spoiler:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
int ch;
size_t count;

count = 0; 
while (1)  {
        ch = getc(stdin);
        switch (ch) {
        case '.':
        case ',': count = 0; break;
        case ' ': count++; continue;
        default: for ( ; count; count--) putc(' ', stdout); break;
                }
        if (ch == EOF) break;
        putc(ch, stdout);
        }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: @martialdidit: I see. BTW: Which gets() ?